# What routes are made using 'resources' keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Making a ruby on rails application for a class, and we are not allowed to use the resources keyword, so my routes file looks like this:

```
School::Application.routes.draw do
  # Routes for departments
  get "depts", :to=>"depts#index"
  get "depts/new", :to=>"depts#new"                                              
  post "depts", :to=>"depts#create"
  get "depts/:id", :to=>"depts#show"
  get "depts/:id/edit", :to=>"depts#edit"
  put "depts/:id", :to=>"depts#update"
  delete "depts/:id", :to=>"depts#destroy"
end
```

There is a problem when I try to get to the edit page, and its because I don't know the correct ':as' fields for the routes and can't seem to find them anywhere. Can someone tell me what they would be if I had used the following line?

```
resource :depts
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the **guide on Routing**:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

If you are lazy, ctrl+F "resources :photos"

**UPDATE: for the keyword `:as` with `resources`**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-names

OR

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

**EVEN BETTER: use of `:as` with custom action**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: This doesn't help, it doesn't tell me what you use for the :as fields.

Comment: "Can someone tell me what they would be if I had used the following line?" That wasn't your question?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't it create routes like: get "depts", :to=>"depts#index", :as => "depts". I need to as fields too.

Comment: That second link seems to be the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can find  how the routes will be by using the following command

```
  rake routes
```

which  list out all the configured routes with http methods